# ImageResizer.net with Cache Plugin causing duplicate output cache

Tags: orchardcms, httpmodule, imageresizer

I have a strange issue, whereby when I enable output caching in Orchard CMS and have ImageResizer.net cache plugin enabled, I get duplicated page content (full DOM).  Just for reference, I am deploying to Azure Small Reserved instance.

Any ideas how to resolve this - do I need to create a cache profile for output cache not to cache images as this is taken care of by the cache plugin?

Thanks in advance,

Peter

Diagnostic information:

```
Image resizer diagnostic sheet      2/13/2013 9:07:32 PM

1 Issues detected:

(Warning):  To potentially see additional errors here, perform an image resize request.



You are using paid bundles: Performance Bundle

Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.MvcRoutingShim.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache

Configuration:

<resizer>
<diagnostics enableFor="allhosts" />
<pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" />
<plugins>
<add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
<add name="DiskCache" />
</plugins>
</resizer>


Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, scale, stretch, crop, cropxunits, cropyunits, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, ignoreicc, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, anchor, dpi, mode, zoom, 

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi, 

Environment information:

Running Microsoft-IIS/7.5 on Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 and CLR 4.0.30319.17929
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: x86 !! Warning, running as 32-bit on a 64-bit OS(AMD64). This will limit ram usage !!
Executing assembly: D:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
IntegratedPipeline: True

Loaded assemblies:

mscorlib                                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Web                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System                                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Core                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Configuration                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Xml                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Runtime.Caching                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Web.RegularExpressions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
Microsoft.JScript                        Assembly: 10.0.0.0        File: 11.0.50709.17929 Info: 11.0.50709.17929
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment           Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.20710.0    
System.Web.Http.WebHost                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.20710.0    
EnvSettings                              Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 7.1.1976.0     
System.Web.WebPages                      Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.20710.0    
System.Web.WebPages.Razor                Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.20710.0    
System.Web.Mvc                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.20710.0    
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure             Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
App_global.asax                          Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
Orchard.Web                              Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.Framework                        Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Autofac                                  Assembly: 2.6.3.862       File: 2.6.3.862      
System.ServiceModel.Activation           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.ServiceModel.Internals            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.ServiceModel                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
SMDiagnostics                            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Xaml.Hosting                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Web.Extensions                    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
Orchard.WarmupStarter                    Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Microsoft.CSharp                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Xml.Linq                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Web.DynamicData                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
Autofac.Configuration                    Assembly: 2.6.3.862       File: 2.6.3.862      
Castle.Core                              Assembly: 1.1.0.0         File: 1.1.0.0         Info: 1.1.0.0
Castle.DynamicProxy2                     Assembly: 2.1.0.0         File: 2.1.0.0         Info: 2.1.0.0
ClaySharp                                Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
FluentNHibernate                         Assembly: 1.3.0.733      
Iesi.Collections                         Assembly: 1.0.1.0         File: 3.3.1.4000      Info: 1.0
ImageResizer                             Assembly: 3.2.4.698       File: 3.2.4.698       Info: 3-2-4  Commit: 4b94e40
ImageResizer.Mvc                         Assembly: 3.2.4.698       File: 3.2.4.698       Info: 3-2-4  Commit: 4b94e40
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache           Assembly: 3.2.4.698       File: 3.2.4.698       Info: 3-2-4  Commit: 4b94e40
log4net                                  Assembly: 1.2.11.0        File: 1.2.11.0        Info: 1.2
MySql.Data                               Assembly: 6.5.4.0        
Newtonsoft.Json                          Assembly: 4.5.0.0         File: 4.5.8.15203    
NHibernate                               Assembly: 3.3.1.4000      File: 3.3.1.4000      Info: 3.3.1.4000
NHibernate.Linq                          Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
NuGet.Core                               Assembly: 1.1.0.0        
Orchard.Core                             Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
System.Data.SqlServerCe                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.8482.1      Info: 4.0
System.Net.Http                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Net.Http.Formatting               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.20710.0    
System.Web.Helpers                       Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.20710.0    
System.Web.Http                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.20710.0    
System.Web.Razor                         Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.20710.0    
System.Web.Abstractions                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Web.Routing                       Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Data.Linq                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Drawing                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.ComponentModel.Composition        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
System.Runtime.Serialization             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
DynamicProxyGenAssembly2                 Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
Contrib.ProjectionLayouts                Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
Orchard.Forms                            Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.Projections                      Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.Alias                            Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.Tokens                           Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.Autoroute                        Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.jQuery                           Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.PublishLater                     Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.Scripting                        Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.Themes                           Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.Widgets                          Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.ContentPicker                    Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
Orchard.Blogs                            Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.Comments                         Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.Disqus                           Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
Orchard.Rules                            Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.Media                            Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.MediaPicker                      Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Szmyd.Orchard.Modules.Sharing            Assembly: 0.0.0.0               
Lucene                                   Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.Users                            Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
System.Web.ApplicationServices           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
Orchard.Roles                            Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.ContentTypes                     Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.DesignerTools                    Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.Fields                           Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
Orchard.Indexing                         Assembly: 1.4.1.0         File: 1.4.1          
Orchard.Modules                          Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.Packaging                        Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
System.Data.Services.Client              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
Orchard.Pages                            Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.Recipes                          Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.Search                           Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.Tags                             Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Orchard.Warmup                           Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
SysCache                                 Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
TinyMce                                  Assembly: 1.6.0.0         File: 1.6            
Vandelay.Industries                      Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
MovieRentalOffers                        Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
System.Data                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Transactions                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.EnterpriseServices                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Numerics                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
Microsoft.GeneratedCode                  Assembly: 1.0.0.0        
NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2              Assembly: 3.1.0.4000      File: 3.1.0.4000      Info: 3.1.0.4000
ActionRecordProxyAssembly                Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
ContentPartDefinitionRecordProxyAssembly Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
Lucene.Net                               Assembly: 2.9.4.1         Info: 2.9.4
System.Web.Mobile                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Xaml                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
PermissionRecordProxyAssembly            Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
System.Dynamic                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
ContentFieldDefinitionRecordProxyAssembly Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
DynamicProxyGenAssembly2                 Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
DynamicProxyGenAssembly2                 Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
ContentItemRecordProxyAssembly           Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_bjaujelw                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_3ucixrnn                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
DynamicProxyGenAssembly2                 Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_hqpkyqpq                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_4rtpbaer                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_hn4szlb4                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
ContentTypeRecordProxyAssembly           Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_fmcezex3                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_0wv5slaj                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_z1olvxy5                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
ProviderPartRecordProxyAssembly          Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_j0ak4epp                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Could you provide a gist of your diagnostics page output, so we know what assemblies and versions you're running? These details matter.

Answer (score 0):

#### This can be reproduced without ImageResizer, using the following HttpModule:

```
public class BlankModule : IHttpModule {

    void IHttpModule.Init(System.Web.HttpApplication context) {
        //Having any event handlers registered for this event causes cache duplication during the Filter execution
        context.PreSendRequestHeaders -= context_PreSendRequestHeaders;
        context.PreSendRequestHeaders += context_PreSendRequestHeaders;
    }
    void IHttpModule.Dispose() { }
    protected void context_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
}
```

Make sure you register it in Web.Config:

```
   <system.webServer>
     <modules>
       <add name="BlankModule" type="BlankModule"/>
     </modules>
   </system.webServer>
```

#### Register another copy of the module, and you'll get tripled responses, not just doubled.

This is not necccessarily a bug in Orchard.Cache.Contrib; it's more likely a bug in the way ASP.NET handles PreSendRequestHeaders in combination with buffered response filters.

Unfortunately, there's no easy workaround from the ImageResizer side, as ImageResizer needs to be able to set the correct mime-type for an IIS-served file, which means PreSendRequestHeaders.

### Bug reports:

- ASP.NET: https://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/10347
- Orchard Contrib.Cache: https://orchardcache.codeplex.com/workitem/26

Comment: I also have this issue. I will be willing to work through it with you if you are still available. PS I've stepped through the code and I have no idea what is causing it. Maybe a conversation with someone with more knowledge of the pipeline can help though.

Comment: @Carl, shoot an e-mail to support@imageresizing.net, and we can set up a session.

Comment: Please justify your downvotes; they're not particularly encouraging.

Answer (score 0):

Orchard 1.7 and new OutputCache module solves this problem. You can view it here: https://orchardcache.codeplex.com/workitem/26