# Intermittent AcquireRequestState with ImageResizer

Tags: newrelic, imageresizer, episerver

I will do my best to describe what I can. We have a mvc (4) site which uses EpiServer(9) as the CMS. We recently purchased ImageResizer (4) and integrated into it our project and it worked fine on my local machine. Deploying to our test environment we noticed intermittent extended delays when loading pages. Using New Relic, we found that the step that was taking so long, was the AcquireRequestState step. I'm sure this isn't enough detail to debug the issue but any assistance on where to look would be greatly appreciated. The gist is, with ImageResizer we get delays, without ImageResizer, we don't. Yes we are using sessions.

Comment: I recently heard someone having similar problems, and tracked it down to a specific StructureMap version. They upgraded StructureMap, and the problem went away. Not sure if that has any bearing on your issue though.

Comment: @TedNyberg thanks for the reply, I updated my StructureMap versions but with no success, if anything it got worst. At this point the easiest solution would be to remove ImageResizer, which is a shame because we did pay for it. Again thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Which windows versions are you running? Are they the same on test and dev? This is typically an environment issue.

Comment: Are these delays happening on web page requests or image file requests?

Comment: @EricHerlitz my dev and test environments are different. Since we don't gain a great deal of benefit in having ImageResizer on our site, we will most likely just not use it. It may have exposed something that will need to be addressed later on, but for now, we'll put this issue

Comment: @NathanaelJones based on dev tools and new relic, the delays are caused by api and webpage calls. When the webapis calls execute, they run as expected. The problem we are seeing is that, there is a long delay until they actually get executed. Approx 110,000+ milliseconds is the average. Usually I see 3 or more calls pending in dev tools

Comment: Try dropping in an empty HttpModule, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777337/imageresizer-net-with-cache-plugin-causing-duplicate-output-cache

You may also consider running ImageResizer in a separate virtual folder or app.

Comment: @NathanaelJones when I get some time to test it I will. We've since moved on. My last resort, if your suggestion doesn't work is to do some tracing via IIS, to try to figure out where exactly the delay is occurring. I would have done it earlier but it's not really something I've done before

Comment: This is pretty common version, but it depends on your server version. The Hotfix Rollup 2828841 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2828841 might be the solution

Comment: @EricHerlitz I did see that but our test env is running 2012R2 and IIS8

Comment: Are there any other services installed on the server that may interfere with your session/states? In example NewRelic? And in that case is NewRelic or similar installed on the other environments?

Comment: @EricHerlitz apart from New Relic, I'm not sure. We also use F5, if that makes a difference. Honestly I don't know, its not really my area of expertise, nor was I the one who created the site

Comment: I've seen New Relic causing these effects when combined with other monitoring software. A typical first try is to remove the `session_start` from global.asax even if it's empty. Other than that try to uninstall F5 and or new relic and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

ImageResizer doesn't get involved in that phase of the request; it uses PostAuthorize and PreSendRequestHeaders exclusively, both of which happen much later.

A blank HttpModule with 1 (or no events) registered will often be able to reproduce issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue on our website. New Relic showed us the long delays in *AcquireRequestState* step of transaction.
We resolved this issue by disabling session with the [SessionStateAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.sessionstateattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) added to the controller that resizes images. Actions of the controller are called in JS with Ajax.

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
```